# IE 11 HTML5 video flashes a black screen between displaying the poster image and the playing of video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm having an issue with an auto-playing video in IE11, works fine everywhere else.

The video is meant to be an animated background, autoplays on start and loops seamlessly.

In all other browsers the poster image loads, and the video immediately begins playing after being loaded.

The same thing happens in IE 11, except between displaying the poster image and playing the video there is a flash of black before the video plays initially.

Everyone in our company uses IE mainly, so everyone thinks something is broken.

It happens every time the page is loaded or refreshed, regardless of whether or not the video has been cached locally.

The code looks like this:

```
<video autoplay loop class="video-background" preload="none" muted plays-inline poster="@poster">
     <source src="@Model.VideoUrl" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video is 1920x1080 with H.264 compression.

Nothing I do seems to fix this issue in IE, and I am trying to avoid doing anything hacky in JS to fake-fix this.

Another developer recommended not adding a poster image, but instead adding an image element to the page above the video element, adding the "onplay" attribute to the video and adding JS inside that to hide the image after a specified amount of time.

While this does fix the issue, there will always be an artificial delay, which I do not like.

Is anyone aware of a correct fix for IE to prevent this black flash of content or is this a browser bug?

Comment: This is a browser issue and should be reported (although I doubt there will be much fixes issued for IE11). The only workaround is to use for example the mentioned fake-fix.

Comment: I actually had a better luck binding to `onloadeddata` event like that:


`<video autoplay loop muted playsinline style="visibility: hidden;" onloadeddata="var s=this;setTimeout(function(){s.style.visibility='visible';},100);">`

This also seems to bind to the probably the most correct event - i.e. when the current frame of the video is loaded (which would be the first frame). IE seems to kinda still need a little timeout because… reasons? But I think that would be a better closer to reality binding than just `onplay` one